Entire functions composed with no entire ones
I need an example of two functions, one of them, $h(z)$, an entire one. The other, a function $g: {\Bbb C\to \Bbb C}
$; where $(h \circ g) (z)$ is entire but $g$ is not.
For example, if $g(z) = e^z$ and $f(z)=\operatorname{Log}(z)$ this doesn't work because $e^z : {\Bbb C \to \Bbb C^*}$ and in the case of $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ its domain doesn't include a semi straight line.

How about $h\equiv 0$?

Taking $h$ to be a constant works for all $g$-functions. We may also take $h(z)=z^2$ and $g$ to be (everywhere) discontinuous with values $\pm1$, each of the two values taken. (For instance $1$ on complex numbers with both components being rational, else $-1$.)

Here's a more non-trivial example:
Take $h$ to be entire and even (for example $h=\cos$), take any non-zero entire function $f$, and define $g$ by
$$g(z)=\begin{cases}
f(z),&\operatorname{Re}(z)\in\mathbb Q,\\
-f(z),&\operatorname{Re}(z)\notin\mathbb Q.
\end{cases}$$
Then $g$ is clearly not entire, but $h\circ g=h\circ f$ as $h$ is even, which is entire as $h$ and $f$ are.

Just choose $h(z) =0$. Then $(h \circ g) (z) =0$ is also entire.
Note that $g : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ can be any function that is defined on $\mathbb{C} $ that is not entire, say $g(z) = \overline{z} $.

Thanks for your answer. I thought that too but I desire to find a non null function and notice than null function ${\Bbb C\to 0}$

This does not answer your question, but is still worth mentioning. Suppose that the function $g$ is continuous and that $h$ is non-constant. Then $h'$ is not identically zero, and thus its zeros must be isolated.
Suppose now that $z_0$ is not such that $h'(g(z_0))=0$. Then $h$ is locally invertible around $g(z_0)$ on a disk. Now we for all $z$ close enough to $z_0$, $g(z)$ will be in this disk since $g$ is continuous. Locally we thus have $g(z)=h^{-1}\circ h\circ g(z)$ which means that $g$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$.
Now suppose there is a sequence of points $z_n\to z_0$ (and $z_n\neq z_0$) such that $h'(g(z_n))=h'(g(z_0))=0$. Since the zeros of $h'$ are isolated and $g(z_n)$ tends to $g(z_0)$, for large enough $n$, $g(z_n)=g(z_0)$. But then $h\circ g$ is constant on the non-isolated set $\{z_n\}_{n=N}^\infty$ and $z_0$, which implies that $h\circ g$ is constant on all of $\mathbb{C}$. We want to show that this implies that $g$ is constant (and therefore holomorphic). Firstly if $g(z)$ are all zeroes of $h'$ then $g$ must be constant because the zeroes of $h'$ are isolated and $g$ is continuous. So suppose instead that $h'(g(a))\neq 0$ for some $a\in\mathbb{C}$. Let $S=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:g(z)=g(a)\}$. Note that $S$ is nonempty (since $a\in S$), and $S$ is closed because $g$ is continuous. Now it must also be open because of the local invertibly of the function $h$ at the point $g(a)$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is connnected, $S=\mathbb{C}$ and $g$ is thus constant.
Since we cannot have $g$ holomorphic this implies that the set $T=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:h'(g(z))=0\}$ is isolated. Now for $z$ outside $T$, $g$ is holomorphic. And for each of the isolated points in $T$, $g$ must be holomorphic aswell because of Riemann's theorem on removable singularities (and the continuity of $g$). And $g$ is thus entire, a contradiction!
We conclude that we cannot both have $g$ continuous, non-entire and $h$ non-constant. Note also that all examples given were either examples where $g$ was non-continuous, or $h$ was constant.

"Locally we thus have $g(z)=h^{-1}\circ h\circ g(z)$
which means that $g$
is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$." How do you conclude this though?

Oh, a typo! $h$ is locally invertible around $g(z_0)$ and $h\circ g$ and $h^{-1}$ are both holomorphic.
